# Circumventing the const requirement of parameters for a custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, custom-attributes

I'm looking for ways to circumvent the restrictions on attribute parameters when creating a custom attribute. Specifically, I have a custom DisplayName attribute that goes and retrieves data from the database and then determines what to display in the LabelFor helper on the view. This is part of a larger prototype, so code refinement is a secondary concern right now. We'll be implementing caching and other performance refinements when we're ready to start developing the actual project. I can provide some context for my actual problem, but I'm hoping answers will be general enough to apply to any type of attribute that needs to do this.

The constructor doesn't do any work besides assigning parameters to some private properties:

```
public DisplayNameTranslationAttribute(string pageName = "", [CallerMemberName] string fieldName = "")
{
    _pageName = pageName;
    _fieldName = fieldName;
}
```

All of the heavy lifting occurs in the DisplayName override method. The reason for this is that DisplayName is called every time the page loads, as opposed to the constructor which is called only once when the page is first loaded and then never again.

```
public override string DisplayName
{
    get
    {
        string displayName = string.Empty;

        _customerID = 1; //This needs be accessed or retrieved somehow, from somewhere

        using (var db = new SomeDataEntities())
        {
            SomeData sd =
            db.SomeDatas.FirstOrDefault(t => t.PageName == _pageName && t.FieldName == _fieldName);

            SomeOtherData od = null;

            if (sd != null)
            {
                od = sd.SomeOtherDatas.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == _customerID);
                displayName = Equals(od, null) ? sd.ColumnN : od.ColumnZ;
            }
        }

        return displayName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? _displayName : displayName;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm right now hard-coding _customerID to 1. I need to be able to provide an actual value to _customerID. I know that I can't pass it as a parameter directly to the attribute, so what I need to do is discover methods to circumvent this restriction. Are there any options to trick the attribute or, more likely, retrieve the ID from somewhere else in memory?

Answer (score 3):

I never could imagine Display attribute could be miss-used like that. Please stop doing that!

If label name is taken from DB, then it is likely part of the domain knowledge and should not be treated like a view logic (which `DisplayName` attribute is).

Instead of having to do these hacks, just get this information with ViewModel that is passed from controller to the view. And controller will take the data from DB. Simple!

```
// pseudo-code
public ActionResult Indes(int customerId)
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.Value = dbContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == customerId);
    viewModel.DisplayName = dbContext.FieldNames.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == some condition);

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**EDIT**: As a second thought, you can try create your own attribute, completely separate from Display Attribute, place there what field should place there. And then implement [DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that will be giving you correct field names for labels.

See sample [implementation of this Metadata Provider in my little app](https://github.com/trailmax/Amv.Reporting/blob/master/AmvReporting/Infrastructure/ConventionProvider.cs). This is shamelessly stolen from [Jimmy Bogard](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/). This implementation does not do what you need, but shows a sample.

Comment: This is my back-up plan. Unfortunately, this would be applied to just about every single ViewModel in an upcoming project and the number of pages we need to build is not insignificant. This would essentially double the size of every ViewModel we build. This makes implementation and maintenance more of a hassle that I was hoping to avoid by writing an Attribute and just decorating everything.

Comment: But, if at the end of the day the answer really is, "This is a terrible idea!" I won't be opposed to it.

Comment: Yes, this is a terrible idea! Unfortunately there is no simple way for your task. Either load of hacks that will be hard to maintain, or load of extra properties. I can think of a way with implementing some interfaces in a view model and have a filter that will detect interfaces/attributes and populate values into models. But attribute MUST not do that itself.

Comment: Do you have a link to the specific post? Search on the site or through a site search on Google isn't turning anything up for me. I could be searching for the wrong things.

Comment: You mean Jimmy's posts? There is no post on that topic. The Model Metada provider is taken from his book, but it does not do what you want to do, so will need to implement yourself with reflection/attribute detection

Comment: Ah got it. Sorry, that wasn't clear to me in your update. I'll do some additional research on it.

Comment: So, I've found that while I could implement a custom provider, I'd still also have to implement a custom attribute so that I could pass some parameters to it. Since not every single ViewModel property is going to have a dynamically derived label, I'd have to code around that. And, I still have the same issue of passing a non-constant CustomerID to the provider somehow. How is going the provider route better than overriding  the DisplayName string in a custom attribute?